# update_all doesn't seem to work on children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following two models:

```
class Device < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hardware_device
  ...

class HardwareDevice < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :devices
  ...
```

When I do:

```
@hardware_device.devices.update_all(active: false)
```

The active state of the device that is linked to the hardware_device remains true.

If I however run this code:

```
@hardware_device.devices.first.update(active: false)
```

It works fine and the active is set to false.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of the problem.  I had

```
  after_initialize :init

  def init
    self.active ||= true
  end
```

In the Device model.  Changing it into:

```
  def init
    if new_record?
      self.active ||= true
    end
  end
```

Fixed the problem.